# ä character in MailMessage.Subject showing up as Ã¤ in hotmail

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, mvcmailer

**Question**: `ä` character in `MailMessage.Subject` shows up as `Ã¤` in hotmail. In Gmail the `ä` character in the subject looks fine. How do you do you properly encode `MailMessage.Subject` so that the `ä` character doesn't get converted to `Ã¤`?

This is how I create the MailMessage (using [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer)):

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage OrderConfirmation()
    {
        return Populate(x =>
        {
            x.Subject = "Beställningsbekräftelse";
            x.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com", "test.com");
            x.ViewName = "OrderConfirmation";
            x.To.Add(order.Email);
        });
    }
```

I have tried the following:

- x.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
- x.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried not converting it?  Just using your value, since you already have the characters there?

I see some people with the same issue that report that they found their data was already UTF8 so converting it resulted in messed up characters as you report. Using their string value directly solved the display problem in those cases.

I found a lot of people with the same issue, in different contexts using the keywords:

```
     ä character converted to Ã¤ hotmail
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried not converting it - it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: Total bummer.  Does it happen with any other mail providers? Besides Hotmail?

Comment: I would suggest, if possible, that you test out as many mail clients as you can to nail down what is happening. That will also help you in searching for more info about the problem, as I find a LOT of info, it just is not particular to hotmail, and so hard to tell what might or might not help. =)  Outlook express for instance is noted as having issues with encoding due to its default settings, possibly.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If System.Net.Mail does not do this correctly for you, you can try using [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit)'s [MimeKit.Utils.Rfc2047](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Utils_Rfc2047.htm) utility class for encoding and decoding header values.

For the display name of email addresses in `To`, `Cc`, `Bcc`, etc, you'll want to use [EncodePhrase](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MimeKit_Utils_Rfc2047_EncodePhrase.htm) and for `Subject`, etc. you'll want to use [EncodeText](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Overload_MimeKit_Utils_Rfc2047_EncodeText.htm).

Unfortunately these are not really designed to be used with System.Net.Mail as you'll notice that these do not return string, they return byte[] (this is because they are designed to be used internally in MimeKit - they are only public for advanced usage).

That said, since the byte[] returned from these methods is US-ASCII, you could use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (result)` to convert the encoded subject back into a string that you could set on the `MailMessage`. If you are stuck with System.Net.Mail, then this might be your only option. If not, though, I would highly recommend dropping System.Net.Mail and replacing it with [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) and [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) (MailKit is what you can use for SMTP, POP3 and/or IMAP).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Gave me the same result. This is how the raw data looks in hotmail:

Subject: BestÃ¤llningsbekrÃ¤ftelse
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Comment: I'm using MvcMailer. MvcMailer I believe inherit from the System.Net.Mail classes. I have to use MvcMailer since I need to use its templating features. Maybe one option would be to write a new CustomMvcMailerMessage that inherits from MvcMailerMessage? And also write a new custom SMTP class, extending MvcMailer SMTP object using MailKit?

Comment: If the Subject header looks like `Subject: BestÃ¤llningsbekrÃ¤ftelse`, then something is decoding the header and Hotmail is for some reason unable to render it correctly. FWIW, it looks like that is UTF-8 that was converted into a unicode display string using the iso-8859-1 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You must override PopulateHtmlPart on class derived from MailerBase

```
 public override AlternateView PopulateHtmlPart(MailMessage mailMessage, string viewName, string masterName, Dictionary<string, string> linkedResources)
    {
        var htmlPart = base.PopulateHtmlPart(mailMessage, viewName, masterName, linkedResources);
        htmlPart.ContentType.CharSet = mailMessage.BodyEncoding.HeaderName;
        return htmlPart;
    }
```

and set encoding

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage OrderConfirmation()
    {
        return Populate(x =>
        {
            x.Subject = "Beställningsbekräftelse";
            x.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com", "test.com");
            x.ViewName = "OrderConfirmation";
            x.To.Add(order.Email);
            x.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            x.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        });
    }
```